# SSL on nginx acting as a reverse proxy to a node server

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I need to access my nodejs api which is reverse proxied by a nginx server over https. To achieve that I generated a self signed cert at location /etc/nginx and then modified the nginx configuration like below:

```
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name api.something.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;
    ssl on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=500;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.132.176.xx:8888; #private ip
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Now whenever I try to access https://api.something.com I always get a connection refused error in google chrome. Plain http works fine. Any clues?

Comment: https runs on port 443 so you need to listen on that port

Comment: Same thing. See my edit. Still I get the connection refused.

Comment: The line should look like this `listen 443 ssl;`

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: I am stuped. fixed it. Thanks! @Molda